# How to optimally cool an uncooled thermopile array?

Tags: infrared, performance

I have ordered a [MLX90640](https://www.melexis.com/en/product/MLX90640/Far-Infrared-Thermal-Sensor-Array) 32x24 uncooled thermopile array, and I want to squeeze as much performance as I can out of this honestly, pretty bad device. One way I am thinking of doing this is through cooling the module down, which based on my limited understanding of the theory behind thermopiles, should reduce the random noise in the sensor, somewhat. However, it is also my understanding that an uneven temperature, would greatly increase pattern noise. What methods may be used to optimally cool a cheaply available thermopile array, using readily available supplies, Ex: a cheap peltier module and heat sink, small copper heat pipe, generic insulating foam, etc.

Comment: I am no expert, but for uniform temperature cool a mass (e.g. block of copper) that it is thermally coupled to while reducing sources of heat by surrounding it with additional cold metal. You will also want to worry about condensing humidity. Usually these things are hermetically sealed with dry nitrogen or similar inside and a fused silica window for visible or near IR, but for thermal infrared your window may have to be silicon or germanium. This is not a simple task!

Comment: As the array is capsulated you do not have a lot of options. Using liquid nitrogen is one of the options, but you need special chamber around the device (created from thermal insulator) . And do not forget nitrogen (even be insulator) must not touch soldering points because tin (metal) become very fragile on low temperatures.

Comment: @uhoh, by capsulated I mean the back of the sensor is not accessible (for cooling for example). And by my understanding the cooling should be done via the cylindrical element.

Comment: Unfortunately the idea with liquid nitrogen is not applicable because by specs working temperature of this sensor is from -40 °C and the temperature of liquid nitrogen is from -196 °C :(

Comment: @topcode What is the _photographic_ application of this thermopile? Is this for machine vision, product inspection, medical imaging, ...?

Comment: What are the physical dimensions?

Comment: @davolfman from what I can tell, just over 1cm diameter, and about 2cm tall. But when it arrives next week i should be able to measure it exactly.

Comment: @Topcode to make a "camera" and image, you'll need to either make a [pinhole camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera) or use a silicon or germanium lens (transparent to thermal infrared). Otherwise it's not a camera. Which leads to (at)scottbb's question, how are you going to do photography with this. It is possible one reason for that question is to help decide if this is on-topic in photography SE. What do you expect to image with your 32x24 sensor? How to do you hope to form an image with it? Maybe that is a good related question for RPi SE or Physics SE. Please ping me if u do

Comment: @davolfman, diameter is about 9.3mm, highness 4.85mm, pins 6mm long. (FOV 110°). iameter is about 9.3mm, highness 11.25mm, pins 6mm long. (FOV 55°)

Comment: @uhoh, even ordinary window glass is transparent to IR, you feel the hot when there is sun on window.

Comment: @RomeoNinov No, This is a thermopile array, sensitive to *thermal IR* which is nothing like near IR (e.g. TV remote controls, security cameras, infrared photographic film, etc.) This doesn't go through glass. Take a household IR thermometer used to measure people's body temperature (pointed at forehead or ear) measure someone's temperature, then put a piece of glass in-between. You are now measuring the temperature of the glass, which looks "black" at thermal wavelengths.

Comment: @RomeoNinov the Sun's output peaks in the visible spectrum, it is a dim, crappy source of thermal IR. Instead, take a hot rock or poker from a fireplace, maybe dimly glowing red. It feels hot. Now put a piece of glass between you and the hot rock or iron, you will NOT feel the heat any more.

Comment: @uhoh It comes with some sort of image forming optics, probably a pretty crappy lens, but the specs dont actually say anything about the lens.

Comment: @Topcode I suspect it's only a flat protective opaque cover that passes thermal IR and blocks visible light; possibly a thin flat piece of double-side-polished silicon wafer, and the thing is mostly a pinhole camera. But if it's really a focusing/imaging optical lens then they should mention the focal length in the specifications. I'm certainly looking forward to hearing the answer!

Comment: @scottbb Well, its main purpose that im buying it for is really just as an exercise in different types of image processing, as I will be combining it with a visual camera, and exploring different methods of integrating the two feeds. But as for practical uses, more or less how you would use any other thermal camera as a consumer, leaks letting cold or hot in, identifying parts of electronics which may be overheating, etc. Cooling it down specifically is realistically overkill and a bad idea for all of this (given it is explicitly recommended against in the manual) but, well, never stopped me.

Comment: @uhoh Finally it has arrived and, definitely not(just) a pinhole, has a pretty clear convex curvature but I couldn't tell you much more than that, given it blocks all visible light, I can just see the reflection of myself in the front surface, which is very small, indicating the curvature.

Comment: @Topcode great! chances are it's silicon or germanium (grayish). If so it should show some conductivity with an ohm meter, but that varies so much with doping and purity (orders of magnitude) that it's hard to say if you'll measure kilo- or mega-ohms. A soft metal tip probably won't scratch those materials but it could leave a spot and damage the optics, so save that test for "tear-down time" in the future. (and if there's an IR anti-reflection coating it will be insulating) You can also estimate the curvature and focal distance and see if it's consistent w/ refractive index about 2.5 (in IR)

Answer (score 3):

**Before designing a cooler for a sensor, always put it in your freezer** (bagged with desiccant if possible to avoid condensation) and verify that cooling to -20C *actually improves performance in the scenario you plan to use it*.  If it doesn't, you've saved yourself a lot of wasted time.

Assuming cooling helps, then here is how I would cool it.  Looking at the datasheet, the power dissipation (typical) is 66 mW, which is a very small thermal load.  Thus a small TEC would have a large effect if properly insulated.  You can buy small metalized TECs that can be directly soldered to chips like this.  Looking at the datasheet mechanical diagram:

[image]

You have 4.7 mm of clearance between the pins.  You directly solder one of these in that space directly to the metal base of the device which acts as its heatsink:

[image]

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/coherent-thermal-solutions/NL1020T-01AC/6159076

Or two larger ones on either side.  Or some other similar product of your choosing.  Then solder the base of the TEC to a heatspreader or heatpipe (both sides are metalized to allow it to be soldered directly to a heatspreader/heatpipe/metal core PCB).  Then pass the data/power pins through that to am underlying PCB (making sure they do not short of course).  You could also use a metal core PCB directly as the heatsink and for data, but you may have to pay extra for one that does through-hole components.

Then you have to insulate the top, but fortunately the application notes have some ideas for that:

[image]

https://media.melexis.com/-/media/files/documents/application-notes/thermal-mechanical-design-recommendations-ir-products-application-note-melexis.pdf?la=en

I think you could probably 3D print that part easily enough, possibly adding some extra space to inject insulating foam or other material around the casing.  That should reduce the heat loss dramatically, allowing your TEC to get well below ambient.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a drilled-out slug of copper could be used as a heat spreader without having any structure to see like a heat pipe.

Given this thing is packaged through-hole with leads on the bottom I suspect it's only meant to be cooled by the ground plane of a circuit board or via a heatsink on the can.  So your cooling requirements might be lower than you think..